# Having an issue with adding file from Git to GitHub for Python

Tags: python, git, github

I am new to Git (Git Bash) and GitHub and I have scoured the internet to try to find a solution to my issue so I thought I would ask here.

I have created a repo in my Github account and cloned it to what I believe is a directory. I am supposed to add a file named hello-world.py to the directory but I am getting an error of `fatal : pathspec 'hello-world.py' did not match any files`

Here are images:

[My github account/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzIVQ.jpg)

[folder which houses it on my PC/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3KHk.jpg)

[And the terminal with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjE8w.jpg)

If anyone could offer advice for a newb, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the image you have attached, you are inside the root folder of your repository in your main branch. If you are trying to add a new file named hello_world.py to this repo, then please do as shown below:

To create a new file called hello_world.py

```
touch hello_world.py
```

Stage the newly created file hello_world.py

```
git add hello_world.py
```

Commit your change to the repo

```
git commit -m "Initial Commit"
```

If you want to make changes again to the hello_world.py, open the file in an editor and make the changes and then again follow the below steps:

```
git add hello_world.py
git commit -m "Added some changes"
```

You can learn how to use github from the below lab link:
[Github Learning Lab](https://lab.github.com/)

Please note all this can be also done using UI application like [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/), so you don't need to remember these commands

Comment: Thank you so much. So touch will create the file, add stages it and commit sends it to my repo?

Comment: yes. you are right.. touch will create an empty file for you , which later you can add contents into it by using any text editor.